# How can I demonstrate the difference(s) between document.documentElement.clientWidth & innerWidth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Reading this [article](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html),

If `document.documentElement.clientWidth|Height` returns the viewport dimensions not including the (vertical?) scroll-bar...

And `innerHeight|Width` returns the viewport dimensions including the (vertical?) scroll-bar...

Why do both properties return the same value on my page even though I have a (automatic) vertical scrollbar?

What would be an example that shows the difference between the two properties?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example that shows the widths being different.

```js
console.log("clientWidth",document.documentElement.clientWidth);
console.log("innerWidth",window.innerWidth);
console.log("visualViewport-width",window.visualViewport.width);
console.log("clientHeight",document.documentElement.clientHeight);
console.log("innerHeight",window.innerHeight);
console.log("visualViewport-height",window.visualViewport.height);
```

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.div{height:500px;background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: Both `clientWidth` & `innerWidth` show the same value and my question was asking for a demonstration when they show different values

Comment: @tonitone120, that must be a browser thing. Because in Chrome on my desktop, they are different.

Comment: Hmm. I presume you use the latest version of Chrome too?

Comment: @tonitone120, I just downloaded it to verify and the numbers are still different. The numbers I'm seeing are: (616 633 200 200)

Comment: I get 633 633 200 200. Would you be able to tell me what you get if you use `visualViewport.height|width`?

Comment: @tonitone120 I updated my answer to show the names next to the values in console, but I get the same as clientWidth/Height

Comment: Would you say the measurement of viewport excluding scroll-bar (width) is more common/useful?

Comment: I get 617 634 617 180 180 180 (Edge Version 87.0.634.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10).